# Mac App Store Search Autocompletion

Tags: mac-appstore

I recognized something strange:
On my MacBook Pro (Mid 2008, Mavericks) I get suggestions when searching in the Mac App Store.
But on my MacBook Air (Late 2010, Mavericks) I don't get them.
[image: MacBook Air]
[image: MacBook Pro]

Comment: Are both connected to the internet and logged in iTunes?

Comment: Yes, they are connected to the same WiFi, and they are logged in to the same Apple ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option and restart the Mac App Store.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]